# What should I do to get xi:include to be recognised and my specified dtd file used?

Tags: nxml

Pretty simple xml file with:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE book PUBLIC "-//OASIS//DTD DocBook XML V4.4//EN"
                      "../../../../tools/docbook-dtd-4.4b2/docbookx.dtd"
[
<!ENTITY % vers   SYSTEM "../../../../doc_developer/version.xml">
%vers;
]>

<book>

  <bookinfo>
    <title>SuperDuper Product Test High-Level Requirements</title>
    <subtitle>Release &superduper_prod_dot_version;</subtitle>
    <pubdate>&superduper_prod_date;</pubdate>
    <xi:include xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude" href="../../../../doc_developer/copyright/copyright.xml" />
  </bookinfo>

  <xi:include xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude" href="high_level_requirements_intro.xml" />
  <xi:include xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude" href="reqs_refs_docbook.xml" />
  <xi:include xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude" href="high_level_requirements_context.xml" />
  <xi:include xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude" href="reqs_content_docbook.xml" />
  <xi:include xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude" href="high_level_requirements_guidelines.xml" />

</book>
```

Emacs (or nxml?) selects

```
<uri resource="high_level_requirements.xml" uri="../../../../../../../../../../Program Files/Emacs/emacs-24.3/etc/schema/docbook.rnc"/>
```

as the schema; attempts to use  "XML" -> "Set Schema" -> "File..." to the cited docbookx.dtd fail ("No schema loader available for file extenson 'dtd'") M-x rng-set-vacuous-schema finds the xi:include acceptable. The cited version.xml defines the superduper_prod_dot_version and superduper_prod_date (xlst generates an html file with no problems from this file; fop is unhappy.)

Comment: It was very long time ago, but if memory serves, you needn't set up the schema location in any special way: having the path in `doctype` should already do it. However, I think that nxml doesn't use DTD schemas any more, it has to be RNG. There used to be another XML mode for Emacs which did though... `psgml-mode` maybe?

Comment: Thank you, wvxvw. I ended up finding small errors in other locations and my documents now compile properly. The xi:include tags still are unknown to emacs, but knowing that that is not the problem allows me to move on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found some excellent documentation at New Mexico Tech's [nxml mode help page](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/nxml/index.html), describing specifically how emacs locates the schema that it uses and describing the content of the schemas.xml file. The xi:include was apparently not the real problem that I was facing; the real problems were   definitions in included files which did not have  content, just plain text. All is well now.